# How to use twistedweb with django on windows

Tags: python, windows, django, twisted

I'm looking for a super easy way to deploy django application on windows.

Basically my plan is to set up any python web server with my app on it and the boundle everything together using py2exe into a single executable.

I've tried using cherrypy however the newest (3.1.2) server doesn't work with Windows XP with Nod32 antivirus installed.

So I decided to give a try to Twisted. I've only found [Django On Twisted](http://code.google.com/p/django-on-twisted/) but it seams to be quite old (2008) and it use twistd command which is a bit hard to pack into single executable.

Has anyone got a working snipped or good source of info?

Comment: I would love an answer on this! How do you package a django web app for deployement , which will be used purely on an intranet and pref on windows. Setting Up Apache > MySQL + Configuring etc, is time consuming and troublesome. Especially when you are doing everything remotely.

Comment: @lssy making py2exe pack my app was quite time consuming. I had to do that to allow easy deployment to hundreds of machines. I wouldn't suggest doing it for single deployment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found quite nice [blog entry](http://blog.dreid.org/2009/03/twisted-django-it-wont-burn-down-your.html) describing how to run django on twisted trunk.

Here is an example that merge twisted with django app into one file so it can be used from file created by py2exe:

```
# bootstrap your django instance

from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
application = WSGIHandler()

import sys
sys.argv += '-no web --wsgi=<module_name>.application --port=8081'.split() 

from twisted.scripts.twistd import run
run()
```

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest [Portable LightTPD](http://en.wlmp-project.net/downloads.php?cat=lighty) (i.e. the .zip) and [Portable Python](http://www.portablepython.com/wiki/Download).  It is very easy to set up LightTPD for FastCGI, and very easy to set up sqlite and FastCGI with Django in the Portable Python distro.  This is probably your fastest and simplest route to getting an easily-deployable Django app going.  If you aren't using it already, you probably want the [Django book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/143021936X) to help speed things along.

[Instant Django](http://www.instantdjango.com/) has Python 2.6.2 integrated, so perhaps that would serve your needs better.

Comment: The portable python has too old version 2.6.1 (I need some of the bugfixes from 2.6.2)